# Functionality of a priority queue in a hospital?

Tags: pseudocode

So let's say I have a hospital that I'm running and I have 1 doctor and 5 patients. Patient 1 comes in, nobody is in queue so he goes first.

Next, I have 3 other patients. Bob has been waiting 3 hours. Sally has been waiting 2. Jim has been waiting 1. Based on arrival, Bob goes first, then Sally, then Jim. Like a regular queue (FIFO).

Bob goes next. During Bob's exam, Jack comes in and has an axe in his head. Jack needs immediate attention. How would I immediately stop Bob's inspection and swap over to Jack in this priority queue?

What would this look like structurally in pseudo code? Would this need some sort of timer?

I'm struggling to understand how Adaptable Priority Queues work and would like to understand the logic behind them. Not asking for code, but the thought process for this sort of thing.

Something like this: [image: table]

Comment: _"During Bob's exam [...] How would I immediately stop Bob's inspection and swap over to Jack in this priority queue?"_ Priority queue generally handle things _waiting for treatment_. Once the treatment starts, the thing is out of the priority queue. The priority queue is not the solution by itself.

Comment: @YSC I see. So for this example, I would queue everyone who had already been waiting, then based on the timer interval (say 76 seconds in), I would then queue in the "emergency case." The emergency case would then skip to the front and I would have to queue the current patient being helped back into the queue?

Comment: Yes. You could insert the poor lad who've been evinced from the exam room with a "bonus" in a way to make sure they will be next in queue. Note however than I personally won't go to your hospital.

Comment: @YSC Thanks for the help. Cracked a smile while at it. Appreciate it.

Comment: A priority queue would queue by time with groups. Easily enough, a triage condition column could give you what you want, say `1` for serious and `9` for non-serious (however triage is defined). The priority is that when dequeueing, others jump ahead, so certain triage levels always supercedes the time waiting.

Comment: Two priority queues would also seem to be an option, emergency and routine. Always process emergency first, if a routine patient is being seen and an emergency comes in, send the routine back. "Adaptable Priority Queues" is not something I have used. The emergency one might be prioritized by urgency rather than wait time / FIFO (person with axe in head goes before broken leg, even if guy with broken leg waited 4 hours).

Comment: Technically, what's being described is an interrupt to the patient process (like `SIGINT`). Knowing whose next (axe in the head is probably not great, maybe spider bite) is the queue bit, which is really easy. No two tables in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's being described is a combination of a signaling system like [POSIX signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#Sending_signals), with an actual queue/dequeue process, where you simply need to promote certain patients ahead of others *at the time of dequeueing*, I would guess by seriousness (triage). Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT patient_id
FROM wait_list
WHERE queue_status = 'awaiting service'
ORDER BY triage_code, queue_dt          # queue_dt is a Date/Time
```

Where `triage_code` might have a mapping like:

```
1 # Very serious
3 # Serious
5 # Stable
7 # Stable Non-Serious
9 # Non-Serious
```

With the last group maybe vaccinations and the like. Make it sparse to give you a little growth, maybe, or just use `1-3`. I've done this recently, it works well enough. Just keep a mapping of the numbers handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `state` field to inform you about the current patient treatment state that can be:

- `waiting`
- `interrupted`
- `finished`
- `examining`
  ...

And have a table where you register the last interrupted patient and the last patient with serious problem that you are going to examine first.

So that you can be able to track the lastly interrupted patient and call him back after you finish with the one having serious problems.

I think that can work